# Movie from the 90s about a boy in the Arctic pole who wakes up in a stasis capsule

Tags: story-identification, movie

A 17-18-old teenager boy wakes up from stasis. He is alone in some capsule in Antarctics or the North Pole. Everything is dazzling white and scary. I don't remember the ending.

Comment: I recommend going to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for help on how to importe tout question.

Comment: What happens after he wakes up?

Comment: He is seeing all White antartics around him, and no people. I have a vague memory he might be looking for his parents but I am not sure.